# Angular - Multiple modules

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have 2 seperated modules which has completly different designs. Therefore I want to create a own module "accounts". If I include the line `import { AppComponent as Account_AppComponent} from './accounts/app/app.component';` then the index.html module is shown. It doesn't solve app-root there. I think I forgot a import.

How I run two separate distinguish routing-tables? Why isn't it showing my design with content?

app-module.ts(shortened):

```
import { AccountsModule } from './accounts/accounts.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AccountsModule,
  ],
})
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent }          from './app.component';
import { MainComponent }          from './main/main.component';
import { KontakteComponent }          from './kontakte/kontakte.component';

import { AppComponent as Account_AppComponent} from './accounts/app/app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'index', component: MainComponent }, 
  { path: 'kontakte', component: KontakteComponent }, 
  { path: 'accounts/app', component: Account_AppComponent, outlet: 'aux' },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

accounts/accounts.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent, HeaderComponent, AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class AccountsModule { }
```

accounts/app/app.component.html:    It contains only content which should be in the layout.

accounts/header/header.component.html:  Contains only the Header.

accounts/main/main.component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
  <body>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <main>
      <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Still the same situation. The  is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import AppRoutingModule inside your app-module.ts

```
import { AccountsModule } from './accounts/accounts.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AccountsModule,
    AppRoutingModule 
  ],
})
```

so in your account module remove `AppRoutingModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent, HeaderComponent, AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AccountsModule { }
```